# Source control integration - read only files - won't compile?

Tags: node.js, webstorm, nativescript

I'm facing a situation with read only files ( which are read only becuase they are under source control)

But when they are in read only state - `tns run` which is a cmd  command - doesn't run.

for example , all files are in check in :

[image]

lets run `tns run android`  :

[image]

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\NS\dev\dsapp1\app\app.android.css'

so let's deal with that css :

[image]

let's run again :

[image]

so you that other files is also in read only

**Question**

How can I run tns run android without(!) check out all files ?

It is not a realistic situation where I'm forced to check out all files just to compile ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well not solving your question directly but definitely giving a possible work around:
check-out all files for edit and do your stuff.
just before check-in run TF power tools command (or tee-clc on mac) with 'uu -recursive' as params and it will undo checkout of unchanged files.

Hope this helps!

For win:

[image]